# how do I query that update at line specific?

Tags: sql

i using sql-server how i can do query
that update or select item at line 3
like

```
update Persons set Fname='name',Lname='lname' game="hmm" where line =3
```

if there no option there something similar i can use to update a line in database
if known that there option to be 2 same/perfect same 2 Rows in my DataBase

There no Primary key

Comment: what is the name of the table you are updating? That should be immediately after the word "update". Does the table have a primary key? if so on what column(s)?

Comment: Your right wait i will do update

there no Primary key cause can be 2 same similar rows

Comment: can you provide example data? If there is no PK whether you can update a specific row depends on whether or not there are any duplicate rows, if there is a row on the table identical to the one you are trying to update the best way would be to apply a row_number() over the table

Comment: Persons:
Fname|Lname|game|hobby
-----------------------
asaf|sh|football|computer
-------------------------
yaron|ed|none|goldSmith
-----------------------
asaf|sh|football|computer

something like that 
i just wanna do like that and do query that update the line 3
to something else

i cant give you example cause i dont have right now
i had long time ago

Comment: SQL tables are unordered sets.  There is no such thing as the third line.

Comment: i just give it as example...

there no option to Update,Delete at row 3???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the row of interest were the third row as appearing below (this is the example data you gave):

```
Fname   Lname   game        hobby
asaf    sh      football    computer
yaron   ed      none        goldSmith
asaf    sh      football    computer    <--- This is the row you want to update
```

You could run the following UPDATE statement to change the row I've indicated. This is best looked at as not the "third row" but as the row where the fname is currently 'asaf', lname is 'sh', game is 'football', and hobby is 'computer'

```
with sub as(
select p.*, row_number() over (partition by fname, lname, game, hobby
                               order by fname, lname, game, hobby ) as rn
from persons p)
update sub
   set fname = 'new_fname', lname = 'new_lname', game = 'new_game'
 where rn = 1
   and fname = 'asaf'
   and lname = 'sh'
   and game = 'football'
   and hobby = 'computer';
```

**Fiddle example:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83fb0/1/0

The above will update one of the 2 rows having values you're targeting. Keep in mind that there is no such thing as "order" with respect to the rows on the table. Also, you should add a primary key so that in the future you can uniquely update specific rows without having to rely on row_number()

Comment: @AsafShazar I just added a query that will update only one of the 2+ rows, in the event there are 2+. However you should add a primary key to the table so that you don't have to take the extra steps taken above (among other reasons).